# Declined Not an answer flag

Tags: support, declined-flags

I got a decline on my "Not an answer" flag on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770726/jmeter-cant-split-string-with-in-beanshell-sampler/51771386#51771386) of the OP just commenting that it works:

> Nevermind. line.split(Pattern.quote("|")) works fine.

Which was included in his question:

> I'm trying to write a beanshell sampler in JMeter that splits a | delimited file. Earlier, it was comma delimited, and using line.split(",") worked fine. Now, I have tried using line.split("|"), line.split("\|"), line.split("\|"), **line.split(Pattern.quote("|")**

Decline reason

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Also, there are two more comments that agree that this question isn't an answer.

Can the declination be removed/undo?

Notice I marked as *Not an answer* before the question was closed.

Comment: That isn't important, this Q+A needs to be deleted.  It has enough DVs now so that users can vote to delete.  Two more to go.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't have option to delete Q or A.

Comment: You will, it just takes a wee bit of patience.  Or a lot of patience to get to 20K, go for the wee today.

Comment: You can vote to delete Q's at 10k - they have just to have been closed for 48 hours first.

Comment: Same [happened to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778179/problems-adding-custom-css-to-vuetify-component/51800804#51800804) lol. Answer provides what OP originally stated that didn't work.

Comment: @Traxo OP's are known to specify things pretty much arbitrarily. If an OP sepcifies in their question that they've tried using the command to turn error reporting on, and that it doesn't work, I know that they are wrong. The command works, and they're in a PEBKAC, and they need to be told so.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Sure, it's possible. But do you not consider that problem might also be something else? If the answer provided in case I linked to really solves the OP's problem, then the question is indeed duplicate of the one mentioned in OP for which he explicitly stated that the solution does not work, and thus is looking for another solution. Actually then it's duplicated question in the first place lol, just needs a bump with another answer or something... I dunno. So confusing.

Answer (score 9):

This

> Nevermind. line.split(Pattern.quote("|")) works fine.

*is* an answer. The OP was looking for something better and decided that what they had worked fine. It's not a particularly good answer, but it is still an answer.

There is definitely an argument for closing and then deleting the question, which can be done by the community - which I see has already happened.

> Can the declination be removed/undo?

No it can't, sorry. However, if the rest of your flagging is fine then one or two declined flags once in while won't have any impact on your ability to flag in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Flags cannot in normal circumstances be changed after having been marked as declined, disputed or helpful.

Also, while this seems like an off-topic Q&A altogether, this is still most certainly an answer.

In a typo question, saying that "you forgot the a" is the answer to the off topic question.

Your attention would have been better used flagging the *question*, or casting close/delete votes on it. The answer itself, while poor, is the answer to the equally poor question.

Comment: 1. Can I ask for a feature to rollback declined flag? 2. Actually I was closing question, but it was closed immediately, so I thought answering something like "it was working after all " isn't a valid answer

Comment: @user7294900 You can write a new question tagged as a feature-request that asks for the possibility for mods to rollback flag decisions, but I don't think it will fly very high...

Comment: Strictly speaking, spam and r/a flags can be changed from helpful to dismissed, but I believe that's it, and it's a special case because of the unusual semantics of helpful spam/r/a flags (-100 rep and feeding into SpamRam).

Comment: @Nathan I'm guessing you meant "disputed" there and not "dismissed" but muscle memory ending up typing the later anyway :)

Comment: @JonClements: Yeah, I wasn't real super awake at the time.